# Elasticsearch cluster is slow for doing parallel calls

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am using elasticsearch cluster of 8 nodes. The data is size approx 1.5TB and the if am doing parallel requests the cluster is responding very slow.

The machine's capacity is 500GB SSD harddisk and 64GB ram. The heap size also increased to 30GB on each machine. 
In the log file. I found these logs:

> 100 org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [Hostname][0.0.0.0:9300][indices:data/read        /search[phase/query]]
>       101 Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsRejectedExecutionException: rejected execution of org.ela        sticsearch.transport.TcpTransport$RequestHandler@8ee60b on EsThreadPoolExecutor[search, queue capacity = 1000,         org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsThreadPoolExecutor@c8c87d4[Running, pool size = 13, active threads =         13, queued tasks = 1000, completed tasks = 46331944]]
>       102     at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsAbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(EsAbortPolicy.java:50) ~[elasti        csearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
>       103     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:830) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>       104     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1379) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>       105     at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsThreadPoolExecutor.doExecute(EsThreadPoolExecutor.java:94) ~[        elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
>       106     at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsThreadPoolExecutor.execute(EsThreadPoolExecutor.java:89) ~[el        asticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
>       107     at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.handleRequest(TcpTransport.java:1343) [elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:        5.1.1]
>       108     at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.messageReceived(TcpTransport.java:1242) [elasticsearch-5.1.1.ja        r:5.1.1]
>       109     at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4MessageChannelHandler.channelRead(Netty4MessageChannelHandler.j        ava:74) [transport-netty4-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
>       110     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373)         [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
>       111     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)         [netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
>       112     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:351) [        netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
>       113     at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293) [netty-codec-        4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]

Is there any way to optimize the response timings.

Comment: Please provide more details about cluster topology: slave count, replica count. It is not clear - do you use one server and 8 nodes? each dedicated for every node? How many hardware CPUs? According to logs you have a server with 8 CPUs - am I right?

Comment: Yes, I used 8 CPU's(8 servers). In the cluster total, we are having 40 indices and 1 replica.

Comment: Also please provide your query if possible and schema mapping file. According to your stack trace you have more 1000 requests at time, it is very strange. It will be nice to have system dashboards with used memory cpu utilization, load average, GC stats and internal ElasticSearch(Lucene) memory utilization. At least `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_nodes/*/stats"`